# In Verilog, how can I define the width of a port at instantiation?

Tags: port, verilog

In a Verilog 2001 module, how can I define the width of a port at instantiation?

For example, a multiplier and the module that instantiates it might look like this:

```
module Multiplier #(parameter WIDTH = 8, parameter WIDTH1 = 8, WIDTH2 = 8) (
    output [WIDTH-1:0] product,
    input [WIDTH1-1:0]  factor1,
    input [WIDTH2-1:0]  factor2
);

parameter WIDTHI = WIDTH1+WIDTH2;
wire [WIDTHI-1:0] intermediate_product;
assign intermediate_product = factor1 * factor2;
assign product = (intermediate_product >>> (WIDTHI-WIDTH));

endmodule

module User();

parameter WIDTH_OF_PRODUCT = 8;
parameter WIDTH_OF_FACTOR_1 = 8;
parameter WIDTH_OF_FACTOR_2 = 8;

wire [WIDTH_OF_PRODUCT] product;
reg  [WIDTH_OF_FACTOR_1] factor1;
reg  [WIDTH_OF_FACTOR_2] factor2;

Multiplier #(WIDTH_OF_PRODUCT,WIDTH_OF_FACTOR_1,WIDTH_OF_FACTOR_2) 
    m0(product, factor1, factor2);

endmodule
```

If the widths of the nets in **User** are defined at compile time, is there any way that the widths of the ports in the instantiation of Multiplier can be defined automatically?

I'd like an instantiation that looks like this:

```
Multiplier m0(product, factor1, factor2);
```

That would probably involve changing the definition of the **Multiplier** module.

Keep in mind that these are just examples. The point of my question regards how the two modules are defined with respect to their nets and ports.

Thanks in advance!

Update:

Here is a case that would not work with Multiplier defined as it is:

```
module Top();
parameter WIDE = 8;
parameter NARROW = 4;

wire [NARROW-1:0] narrow_product;
wire [WIDE-1:0]   wide_product;
reg  [NARROW-1:0] narrow_factor_1;
reg  [WIDE-1:0] wide_factor_1;
reg  [NARROW-1:0] narrow_factor_2;
reg  [WIDE-1:0] wide_factor_1;

Multiplier mWide(wide_product, wide_factor_1, wide_factor_2);
Multiplier mNarrow(narrow_product, narrow_factor_1, narrow_factor_2); // PROBLEM

endmodule
```

My motivation for this is that the nets represent *fixed point numbers*, a representation of numbers with fractional parts. I will have to specify a precision for the fixed point numbers. While that could be a global constant, I may want to use different precisions. So, I will probably need parameters to specify the precisions of the ports in modules.

Update:
Well, I can't do what I wanted to do. So here is what I have done, in case this helps anyone:

Since the widths of input and output are the same I defined them this way:

```
module Multiplier #(parameter WIDTH = 8,
    parameter WIDTH1 = WIDTH,
    parameter WIDTH2 = WIDTH1) (
    output [WIDTH-1:0] product,
    input [WIDTH1-1:0]  factor1,
    input [WIDTH2-1:0]  factor2
);

...

endmodule
```

So then I can instantiate this way:

```
Multiplier #(16) m0(product, factor1, factor2);
```

if the product and the factors all have the same length. It's a little less verbose than specifying all of them, especially when I working with fixed point numbers where the instantiation would look like this:

```
Multiplier #(16,8) m0(product, factor1, factor2);
```

where the second number is a PRECISION parameter giving the width of the fractional part. (This would require an update to the Multiplier module definition to include PRECISION, PRECISION1, and PRECISION2 with definitions analogous to the WIDTH definitions.

Comment: But it works *only* in this case...

Comment: If any of the signals `product`, `factor1`, `factor2` have a width other than 8, they don't match the default port width of `Multiplier` anymore. The question is how the port widths can be derived from the widths of the connected signals.

Comment: This has also been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307306/automatic-systemverilog-variable-size-using-interface-width-and-size), but only for SystemVerilog where a solution appars to exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter are defined for exactly his reason you just have to pass the parameters to the instance:

```
module Top();
localparam WIDE   = 8;
localparam NARROW = 4;

wire [NARROW-1:0] narrow_product;
wire   [WIDE-1:0]   wide_product;
reg  [NARROW-1:0] narrow_factor_1;
reg    [WIDE-1:0]   wide_factor_1;
reg  [NARROW-1:0] narrow_factor_2;
reg    [WIDE-1:0]   wide_factor_1;

Multiplier #(
  .WIDTH  (WIDE),
  .WIDTH1 (WIDE),
  .WIDTH2 (WIDE)
) mWide (
  .product (wide_product),
  .factor1 (wide_factor_1),
  .factor2 (wide_factor_2)
);


Multiplier #(
  .WIDTH  (NARROW),
  .WIDTH1 (NARROW),
  .WIDTH2 (NARROW)
) mNarrow(
  .product (narrow_product),
  .factor1( narrow_factor_1),
  .factor2( narrow_factor_2)
); // NOT A PROBLEM

endmodule
```

Multiplier :

```
module Multiplier #(
  parameter WIDTH = 8, 
  parameter WIDTH1 = 8,
  parameter WIDTH2 = 8
) (
    output [WIDTH-1:0]   product,
    input  [WIDTH1-1:0]  factor1,
    input  [WIDTH2-1:0]  factor2
);
//...
```

Comment: Thanks, @Morgan. I thought that that was the case. Since the widths are constants at the top of the module hierarchy, I was hoping the widths could be inferred. Parameters definitely go a long way to making modules more general. If I wanted, I could preprocess the source through Perl or some other language to fill in the widths for me. It's probably not worth it.

Comment: My preference for a pre-compile solution is using rubys erb. A command line parser of mine: [Ruby-it](http://lizard-spock.co.uk/RubyIt/). However each instance would then need to be uniquely named based on the required widths. In verilog it is very common to pass parameters hierarchically as shown in my answer.

Comment: Is there any way that the compiler could infer the wire size/range based on the port(s) connected to it? I know this doesn't work: "wire narrow_product"  without [NARROW-1:0]  dimensions, is there any other way to do that? thanks